# Arduino Due - Multiple Serial Lines

Tags: serial, arduino-due, avr

I'm trying to interface with a serial device utilizing Serial1 (pins 18,19) on the Arduino Due. The normal serial port (Serial) is working just fine and is acting as a debug port at the moment - It's also able to communicate with the serial device without a problem when using the normal port.

I noticed that within the libraries for the Arduino hardware, the avr directory contains HardwareSerial files for the Mega's multiple serial lines, but the header file under the sam director does not. Simply a declaration of the HardwareSerial class with no elaboration on Serial1,Serial2 or Serial3 like the Mega's header contains.

Has anyone modified the libraries to set up the Arduino Due's multiple serial lines? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried Serial2, it definitely works on Due without any modification of any libraries